# General method to solve Combination problems based on binomial series.

Tags: power-series, combinations, binomial-theorem

How can I solve these types of questions:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{28} k^2{28 \choose k}$$
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{28} 3^k{28 \choose k}$$

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of $28Ck$.  Also, note that you can use dollar signs ($$) to signify math in LaTEX format AKA MathJAX.  For example, "n choose x" looks like $n \choose x$.

Comment: I've changed `28Ck` to ${28 \choose k}$ in light of what was probably intended.  I hope you don't mind this notation.

Comment: thanks that is exactly what I wanted to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** The problems are quite different. For the second problem, a good approach would be to experiment with numbers very much smaller than $28$, such as $1$, $2$, and $3$. There will be a strong pattern, and after seeing the pattern you are likely to find a way to show the pattern continues.

But here is a hint that solves the problem quickly.
$$\sum_{0}^{28}\binom{28}{k}3^k=\sum_0^{28} \binom{28}{k}3^k 1^{28-k}.$$
Now think Binomial Theorem.

For the first problem, note that that by the Binomial Theorem,
$$(1+x)^{28}=\sum_0^{28} \binom{28}{k}x^k.$$
Take the derivative of both sides. That will not finish things, but it is a good start.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it was easy, that's why I dealt with it first, needed to warm up!  For the first problem, there are many approaches. One good way is to differentitate, multiply by $x$, differentiate again, set $x=1$.

Comment: but for the first problem I don't understand how does your equation relates to the problem statement because you have written $$x^k$$ but my problem deals with $$k^2$$

Comment: Let $f(x)=(1+x)^{28}$. I will assume you can take care of any differentitations. Then $f'(x)=\sum k\binom{28}{k}x^{k-1}$. So $xf'(x)=\sum k\binom{28}{k}x^k$. So $(xf'(x))'=\sum k^2\binom{28}{k}x^{k-1}$. Now put $x=1$. On the right, we get our desired sum. On the left, just calculate the value of $(xf'(x))'$ at $x=1$. If we have the patience, we could use the technique to find $\sum k^3\binom{28}{k}$, and even higher powers.

Comment: We multiply by $x$ in order to "restore" the $x^k$, so that differentiation will give us another $k$. If we don't, and differentiate again, we get $\sum k(k-1)\binom{28}{k}$, from which we can still pick up $\sum k^2\binom{28}{k}$, since from the first differentiation we can find $\sum k\binom{28}{k}$. A matter of taste. I actually prefer the second way, and am happy at the opportunity to mention both.

Comment: thanks again both the methods are great...
and so is your explanation

Comment: You are welcome. The method used was a *generating functions* approach that you are likely to see again.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

For the first, $$k^2\binom nk=\{k(k-1)+k\}\binom nk=k(k-1)\binom nk+k \binom nk$$

$$=k(k-1)\frac{n(n-1)\cdot (n-2)!}{k(k-1)\cdot(k-2)!\{(n-2)-(k-2)\}!}+k \frac{n\cdot (n-1)!}{k\cdot(k-1)!\{(n-1)-(k-1)\}!}$$
$$=n(n-1)\binom{n-2}{k-2}+n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$ if integer $k>1$

Put $k=2,\cdots,n-1,n$

In general, $$(a_0+a_1k+a_2k^2+a_3k^3+\cdots+a_mk^m)\binom nk$$

$$=b_0 \binom nk+ b_1\cdot n\binom{n-1}{k-1}+b_2 n(n-1)\binom{n-2}{k-2}+\cdots +b_m n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)\binom nm$$

Multiply either sides by $k!$ and compare the coefficients of the different powers of $k$ to find $b_i$s in terms of $a_i$